# How to handle streams on top of RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query, node-streams

I need to handle node streams using the RTK Query endpoints. The problem is that the official doc only includes the [example for sockets](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates), but that scenario doesn't work for Streams.
Here is the endpoint definition:

```js
...

teamSkillsActionableInsights: builder.mutation<Response, TeamSkillsReport>({
      query: (teamSkillsReportData) => ({
        url: "reports/team/skills/actionable-insights",
        method: "POST",
        body: teamSkillsReportData,
        responseHandler: async (response) => response.body,
      }),

...
```

And this is the consumption:

```js
...

const [aiActionableInsights, setAiActionableInsights] = useState("");
const [updatePost] = useTeamSkillsActionableInsightsMutation();

...

const getUserSkillsActionableInsights = async () => {
    const response = await updatePost(teamSkillsReportData).unwrap();

    // Using While Loop
    let total = "";
    const reader = response?.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    while (true) {
      const { done, value: chunk } = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;

      const decodedValue = decoder.decode(chunk);
      total += decodedValue;
      setAiActionableInsights(total);
    }
  };
```

The server streams plain text with `text/plain; charset=utf-8` header.